# phaser/webgl: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, phaser-framework

I'm attempting to render quite a large spritesheet in phaser (2.0.5) in the same way as a smaller one which is working correctly.

I'm loading it like so:

```
game.load.spritesheet('upperArm', '../assets/BodyParts/upperleftarm.png',444,393);
```

and trying to render it:

```
this.upperArm = game.add.sprite(230,150, 'upperArm');
```

I'm just getting a black square in place of the image. The spritesheet itself is 27528px X 393px and I've tried to increase the size to ^2 number dimensions (32768x512) but am getting the same issue.

The working sprite does not have ^2 dimensions but is workign correctly.

When I change the renderer to canvas it works fine (but jerky) so the issue appears to lie with webgl

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graphics card probably does not support such large textures.

You can query the maximum supported texture size using `ctx.getParameter(MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` or have [a look here](http://webglreport.com/). Assuming a maximum supported texture size of `4096` is a safe bet(99%), while a lot(81%) of GPUs support `8192`. Take a look at [webglstats.com](http://webglstats.com/) for more info.